# systemd not executing ExecStop script

Tags: centos, redhat, systemd

I have created a service(name- develop) using systemd. Following is the content of my develop unit file -

```
Description=Develop Manager Service
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile = /home/nayasa/data/var/run/developPid
User=root
Group=root
ExecStartPre = /bin/bash /home/nayasa/control_scripts/develop_startPre.sh
ExecStart =/bin/bash /home/nayasa/control_scripts/develop_start.sh
ExecStop =/bin/bash /home/nayasa/control_scripts/develop_stop.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My *develop.service* forks multiple processes during runtime.
Whenever I run `systemctl stop develop.service` , systemd stops all processs in the CGroup of my develop service whereas the **develop_stop** script that I have provided only kills the main process using pid from pidfile. I want to stop only the main process. It seems to me that systemd is not using my stop script. How do I force systemd to execute my stop script to stop the service and not kill all processes of the Cgroup? FYI- I know that using KillMode option I can direct systemd to kill only main process and leave other processes, but I want to know why is my script not being executed?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little weird to expect orphaned processes to persist after stopping a service.  You would be left with a system that's in an unknown state.  What would happen if you started the service again?

I think what you probably want is more complicated than a single service.

Let's say you wanted `develop.service` to launch `proc1` and `proc2`.  You want `systemctl stop develop.service` to kill `proc1` but not `proc2`.  In this case, you still need something to manage `proc2` otherwise you have a rogue orphaned unmanaged and monitored process.  The answer is to use another service.

Instead, try making two services.  `develop.service` would launch `proc1`, possibly using your scripts.  Then add a `Wants=proc2.service` to your `[Unit]` section.  `proc2.service` would be responsible for `proc2`.

This means `systemctl start develop.service` will launch `proc1` and `proc2`.  Meanwhile `systemctl stop develop.service` will only kill `proc1`. `proc2` can still be stopped/monitored by inspecting `proc2.service`.

Comment: Thanks @Stewart for your suggestion, your point is valid. I agree with your thoughts of orphaned services. But I still do not understand why would systemd not execute my script that is specified in ExecStop? I have verified that my script of ExecStop is not run by using logs. Am I wrong to say that the command that we provide in ExecStop is used to stop the service? If I am right then why is systemd not doing so?

Comment: I'm not sure that `ExecStop=` stdout or stderr will be logged in the journal.  [systemd.service(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) suggests that if `ExecStop=` is not used, SIGTERM is sent to all child processes.  Example 5 suggests that `PIDFile=` is how systemd will stop a `fork` service, so perhaps that doesn't use `ExecStop` if `PIDFile=` is set.  Last suggestion is to try using `Type=oneshot` and `RemainAfterExit=yes`.  This will certainly call both `ExecStart=` and `ExecStop=` but will not consider itself stopped if anything in `PIDFile` stops.